# How to properly work with dynamically-allocated multi-dimensional arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

How do I define a dynamic multi-dimensional array in C++? For example, two-dimensional array? I tried using a pointer to pointer, but somehow it is failing.

Comment: @JustinMeiners Possible, but question is how to use, not how to define. And the conclusions reached by the top-most answers to that question are wrong. You have to go down about 550 upvotes before anyone gets the answer even half right.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing one should realize that there is no multi-dimensional array support in C++, either as a language feature or standard library. So anything we can do within that is some emulation of it. How can we emulate, say, 2-dimensional array of integers? Here are different options, from the least suitable to the most suitable.

## Improper attempt #1. Use pointer to pointer

If an array is emulated with pointer to the type, surely two-dimensional array should be emulated with a pointer to pointer to the type? Something like this?

```
int** dd_array = new int[x][y];
```

That's a compiler error right away. There is no `new [][]` operator, so compiler gladly refuses. Alright, how about that?

```
int** dd_array = new int*[x];
dd_array[0][0] = 42;
```

That compiles. When being executed, it crashes with unpleasant messages. Something went wrong, but what? Of course! We did allocate the memory for the first pointer - it now points to a memory block which holds x pointers to int. But we never initialized those pointers! Let's try it again.

```
int** dd_array = new int*[x];
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i)
   dd_array[i] = new int[y];

dd_array[0][0] = 42;
```

That doesn't give any compilation errors, and program doesn't crash when being executed. Mission accomplished? Not so fast. Remember, every time we did call a `new`, we **must** call a `delete`. So, here you go:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    delete dd_array[i];
delete dd_array;
```

Now, that's just terrible. Syntax is ugly, and manual management of all those pointers... Nah. Let's drop it all over and do something better.

## Less improper attempt #2. Use `std::vector` of `std::vector`

Ok. We know that in C++ we should not really use manual memory management, and there is a handy `std::vector` lying around here. So, may be we can do this?

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > dd_array;
```

That's not enough, obviously - we never specified the size of those arrays. So, we need something like that:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > dd_array(x);
for(auto&& inner : dd_array)
    inner.resize(y);

dd_array[0][0] = 42;
```

So, is it good now? Not so much. Firstly, we still have this loop, and it is a sore to the eye. What is even more important, we are seriously hurting performance of our application. Since each individual inner vector is independently allocated, a loop like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (auto&& inner : dd_array)
    for (auto&& data : inner)
       sum += data;
```

will cause iteration over many independently allocated inner vectors. And since CPU will only cache continuous memory, those small independent vectors cann't be cached altogether. It hurts performance when you can't cache!

So, how do we do it right?

## Proper attempt #3 - single-dimensional!

We simply don't! When situation calls for 2-dimensional vector, we just programmatically use single-dimensional vector and access it's elements with offsets! This is how we do it:

```
vector<int> dd_array(x * y);
dd_array[k * x + j] = 42; // equilavent of 2d dd_array[k][j]
```

This gives us wonderful syntax, performance and all the glory. To make our life slightly better, we can even build an adaptor on top of a single-dimensional vector - but that's left for the homework.

Comment: Upvoted, but worth adding in even more proper attempt 4: Wrap the 1D array in an object to reduce the odds of a typo in the indexing math smurfing you over in one place when it works everywhere else.

Comment: It is right there, last sentence. Left for homework :)

Comment: Would it be worthwhile adding an example for additional dimensions, for instance if someone coming from C# might want to use a 3-dimensional array? I use C# as an example because multi-dimensional arrays are supported by the language.

Comment: @E.Moffat, I myself am not familiar with C#. If you have an example, please feel free to edit my answer - I will look into it in today or tomorrow and will accept.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, yes, but for a self-answered question like this I'd include a really basic wrapper for completeness. Unless you plan on a sequel: Dude, Where's my 'Operator[][]`?

Comment: @SergeyA A hybrid way I was not aware of until recently: `const size_t ROWS = 2, COLS = 3; int (*p)[COLS] = new int[ROWS][COLS]; delete[] p;`

Comment: @user4581301, ok, will update a bit later -gotta run now.

Comment: Sometimes there are reasons to use #2 instead of #3. For example, if the array is very large, growing the number of rows with #3 may either fail due to OOM, or trigger a massive reallocation and copy; whereas #2 does not suffer from that problem (even if it reallocates, the existing rows stay in place)

Comment: @vsoftco you can and should use `std::array` for any dimension that is constant

Comment: @M.M Sure, assuming C++11, which this question should also be tagged as.

Comment: @vsoftco, that's not dynamic.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, indeed, that's why I said "hybrid". The # of rows can be non-constant though, the columns are constant expr.

Comment: A less verbose way to do the initialization in #2 would be: `vector<vector<int>> dd_array(x, vector<int>(y));`